# Finding duplicates based on multiple columns per record

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I need to extract duplicates (and always the newer one/s of them) from only one table. Let's call the table personsToCostcenter. I need to find the duplicates based on two columns, the person_id and the costcenter_id.

How can i do that in SQL?

Sample Data

```
Created               Editor    Person_ID Costcenter_ID
01.01.2019 00:15:15 - A424521 - X00542  - 71341
01.01.2019 00:18:29 - A424521 - X00456  - 71341
01.01.2019 00:19:05 - A424521 - X00410  - 71341
01.01.2019 00:19:07 - A424521 - X01544  - 71341
01.01.2019 00:19:07 - A424521 - X00455  - 71341
01.01.2019 00:20:47 - A424521 - X00879  - 71341
01.01.2019 00:20:58 - A424521 - X00214  - 71341
01.01.2019 00:21:18 - A424521 - X00458  - 71341
01.01.2019 00:23:57 - A424521 - X00542  - 71341
01.01.2019 00:23:59 - A424521 - X00122  - 71341
01.01.2019 00:24:07 - A424521 - X00542  - 71341
```

The desired result here is

```
01.01.2019 00:23:57 - A424521 - X00542  - 71341
01.01.2019 00:24:07 - A424521 - X00542  - 71341
```

Comment: Sql server, mysql, oracle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each duplicate exists at least 1 row with the same data:

```
select * from personsToCostcenter p
where exists (
  select 1 from personsToCostcenter pp
  where
  p.Person_ID = pp.Person_ID
  and
  p.Costcenter_ID = pp.Costcenter_ID
  and
  p.Created > pp.Created
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `created` is unique, you can use `EXISTS` to filter for rows where a duplicate row with a time in the past exists.

```
SELECT *
       FROM personstocostcenter t1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM personstocostcenter t2
                            WHERE t2.person_id = t1.person_id
                                  AND t2.costcenter_id = t1.costcenter_id
                                  AND t2.created < t1.created);
```